# mongoDB error: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install [habitrpg](https://github.com/busterroni/habitrpg) locally but I keep getting a mongoDB error after typing `node src/seed.js`:

```
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

I saw on other questions with the same error people have suggested typing in 'mongod' and that fixes it by creating a local server. I get the error:

```
-bash: mongod: command not found
```

Can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: MongoDB and HabitRPG are both programming tools, so their installation is covered by the site's on-topic rules. This should not have been closed just because some people are recommending (low-quality) non-programming-related solutions.

Answer (score 17):

1. Open CMD (In Windows) or terminal (In Ubuntu).
2. type command >cd PATH_FOR_MONGODB_BIN_FOLDER

   > cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

   for ubuntu command will be same :

   > cd /home/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin
3. then type command >mongod --dbpath PATH_FOR_DATA_FOLDER

   > mongod --dbpath C:\data\db

   For ubuntu command will be :

   > ./mongod --dbpath /home/data/db

   you can specify any folder as data folder.
4. Wait till CMD or Terminal shows "waiting for connections"

   > 2016-09-01T21:38:33.170+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
5. Then open new CMD or terminal window.
6. type command >cd PATH_FOR_MONGODB_BIN_FOLDER   ( same as step 3 )

   > cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

   Don't close previous window of cmd or teminal.
7. then run mongodb by typing "mongo" in windows or "./mongo" in ubuntu

   > mongo

   For ubuntu

   > ./mongo
8. After mongodb run successfully you can close previous CMD window.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have MongoDB installed.  Follow the directions for your system to install it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/

From the habitRPG docs:

> Before starting make sure to have MongoDB, NodeJS and npm and Git installed and set up.

Comment: So I think I've installed it, but now I'm getting the error `Warning: mongodb-2.4.9 already installed, it's just not linked` after typing in  `brew install mongodb`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you don't have an environmental variable declared. Assuming that your MongoDB installation is `C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\YOUR_VERSION_NUMBER\`, you should just add the `bin` folder path of that version of MongoDB to your PATH system environment variable.

Here's a link where you can find the way to do that without complications :
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 1):

After installing MongoDb you have to add the directory "data\db" under the C:\ directory,
then you should start the mongod.exe

Answer (score 1):

on windows open task manager || Ctrl + shift + ESC > select service tab > search for mongo db > right click > start service

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I didn't have MongoDB. So I installed MongoDB and tried to run node application and it worked.

If you don't have MongoDB then follow below steps to install and enjoy

Commands :

```bash
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Then type mongo in terminal and if you will get console for mongo then it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo pip3 install mongodb`, then `sudo pip3 install pymongo`, *then* `mongod`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac.
I updated my Homebrew files, after I reinstaled MongoDB in my terminal

```
 brew tap mongodb/brew
```

and

```
brew install mongodb-community@5.
```

and I started mongo server

```
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

After that I coud to commect.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is the connectoon is down, run script:

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

And up mongoDB Compass and works.

Answer (score -1):

I ran mongodb install file and choose repair