# Mongodb: Invalid Command error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing web application using node js and mongo db. Initially I got this error - failed to connect to [localhost:27017]. I followed the steps in this answer [Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39276869/7697507]. But, after doing the 3rd step, I am getting this error.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve it?

[image: MongoDb: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't allow spaces in paths like this.

Try:
`mongod --dbpath "C:\Users\dell pc\Desktop\Real Safe\final\data"`

With the path in quotes.